# Linq produces wrong groupby output

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

The following code produces the incorrect output. It outputs 10 Keys each with 1 Value. If I delete the ToList() from Games it produces the correct output of 2 Keys each with 5 Values. Also, if it leave the Games.ToList() as is and remove the Dto from the GroupBy, it produces the correct output. How do I get this query to work correctly with the Games.ToList() and the Dto in place? (Games is a sql table. Note: When Games is a list it does not work, but when Games is IQueryable, it works).

```
void Main()
    {
        Games.ToList()
        .GroupBy(g => new MatchDto { MatchdayId = g.MatchdayId, KickOffDate = g.KickOffUtc.Date })
        .Select(grp => new
        {
            Key = grp.Key,
            Values = grp.ToList()
        })
        .Dump();
    }

public class MatchDto
{
    public int MatchdayId { get; set; }
    public DateTime KickOffDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We can't guess what the data is, what output you expected and what you got. There's no reason to use a DTO for grouping. `If I delete ... If I leave` that doesn't explain anything.

Comment: `Games is a sql table.` in that case `Games.ToList()` is a bug - it loads the entire table in memory. The rest is a LINQ-to-Objects query, not a LINQ-to-EF that gets translated to SQL

Comment: Just a small question: why does the ToList need to stay if it works without?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Games` is a list (or you keep the `.ToList()`), the query is executed on the client. There, `GroupBy` will calculate the key (which always is a new `MatchDto` object) and since `MatchDto` does not override `Equals` or implement `IEquatable<MatchDto>`, `GroupBy` correctly treats these as different. If `Games` was an EF table and you removed the `ToList()` call, then the grouping gets transpiled to SQL where the missing implementation of `MatchDto` does not matter.

Hence, it is not that Linq produces a wrong output, it is that your implementation of `MatchDto` is missing a value type semantics that your are expecting but did not implement. The fastest way to implement this value type semantics would be if you turned `MatchDto` into a record.

Comment: _"If Games was an EF table, then the grouping gets transpiled to SQL"_ - no, it will not due to the explicit `ToList` call before the grouping =)

Comment: @GuruStron Right, actually you also have to remove the `ToList()` before the grouping. I am quite sure though that if you did, the query would be transpiled to SQL even though there is the `ToList` inside the key selector of the `GroupBy`

Comment: Thanks Georg, changing class to record does indeed correct the problem. But I would rather implement MatchDto correctly, can you provide code?

Comment: If you need value type semantics, i.e. that two objects should be treated equal iff their properties are equal, then records give you a correct implementation for free.